# Strip Characters after space in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to strip out the characters that are before a space in javascript. See code below:

```
var name = "First Last";
```

How can I strip out "First" and just leave "Last".

Also, Will I get the same results if the var was the below? or would it just output "Last" still? Is there a way to just strip upto the first space?

```
var name = "First Middle Last";
```

Thanks.

Comment: About the "Will I get the same results" part: it's up to you. Depending on what you want, you can solve this problem differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `substr` and `indexOf`:

```
var name = name.substr(name.indexOf(' ') + 1) ;
```

Comment: So many upvotes and no explanation to how his code is working.

Answer (score 2):

Regex: `(.*?)\s`

Explanation:

```
1st Capturing group (.*?)
.*? matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
```

---

```js
newStr = "First Middle Last".replace(/(.*?)\s/, "");
console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
name = "First middle last";
var name = name.substr(name.indexOf(" ")+1);

document.body.innerHTML += name;
```

Will get the part after the first space.

You will need to things for this: `substr` and `indexOf`.

- The first takes part of a string `substr(starting pos, end pos)`
- The second calculates the position of the first occurrence of the variable. The +1 is needed or else the space would be included.

Comment: This will leave only "last" but OP wants only the first word stripped.

Comment: Thanks, But I need the part after the first space.. So "First Middle Last" would become "Middle Last"..

Comment: @ScottThornton, Misread, changed to `indexOf`. Same principle stands.